# JSS deploy config to XM Cloud failed

Tags: jss, nextjs, xm-cloud

I'm using Sitecore XM Cloud environment, and I setting up my next.js app to connect to Sitecore editors.
I'm currently following this [article](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--connecting-a-next-js-jss-app-to-sitecore-editors.html).
After setting up the configuration file and run `jss deploy config`, I got the following error

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/App_Config/Include/zzz'
> at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1390:3)
> at module.exports.makeDirSync (/Users/user/Documents/XMCloud/xxx/xxx.XMC.Websites/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir.js:23:13)
> at deploy (/Users/user/Documents/XMCloud/xxx/xxx.XMC.Websites/node_modules/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-dev-tools/dist/cjs/deploy.js:21:28)
> at Object. (/Users/user/Documents/XMCloud/xxx/xxx.XMC.Websites/node_modules/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli/dist/cjs/scripts/deploy.config.js:58:45)
> at Generator.next ()
> at fulfilled (/Users/user/Documents/XMCloud/xxx/xxx.XMC.Websites/node_modules/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-cli/dist/cjs/scripts/deploy.config.js:5:58) {
> errno: -2,
> syscall: 'mkdir',
> code: 'ENOENT',
> path: '/App_Config/Include/zzz'
> }

This is my scjssconfig.json content

```
{
  "sitecore": {
    "instancePath": "",
    "apiKey": "<api key>",
    "deploySecret": "<deploy secret key>",
    "deployUrl": "https://xxx.sitecorecloud.io/sitecore/api/jss/import",
    "layoutServiceHost": "https://xxx.sitecorecloud.io/"
  }
}
```

I have 2 questions here

1. I'm suspecting the error is due to the missing instance path. But I'm using XM Cloud, where can I get the actual path? Do I need to raise Sitecore support to get it?
2. The `sitecoreConfigPath` defined in package.json is set to `/App_Config/Include/zzz`. It is a must to deploy to this folder path?

Comment: you are not following the Next.js setup for XM Cloud - you shouldn't be using `jss config deploy` on XM Cloud. Follow this guide instead: https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/getting-started-with-xm-cloud.html

Comment: Rich has said this above. With XM Cloud if you are setting up the full stack locally, you should follow the doc https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--setting-up-your-full-stack-xm-cloud-local-development-environment.html
The doc reference is for XP/XM setups with JSS. You shouldn't need to run jss config for XM Cloud setup.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you are following the correct documentation and using the correct github repository.
The xmcloud work differently and you need to use Sitecore CLI for deployment.

Getting Started: https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/getting-started-with-xm-cloud.html

Deploy: https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/the-cloud-deployment-command.html
https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/xm-cloud-deploy-app.html

You can check out the demo from Andy Cohen for deployment on youtube :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a23g2TRUvOI&ab_channel=AndyCohen

I hope it helps